# jquery-week-calendar Import Ics event

Tags: jquery, events, calendar, icalendar

I use jquery week calendar ([demo](http://themouette.github.io/jquery-week-calendar/weekcalendar_demo_2.html)) and I want to use event from an ical (.ics).

I don't find anything on the net or in the documentation,

This is the part of the code :

```
  var eventData1 = {
    options: {
      timeslotsPerHour: 4,
      timeslotHeight: 20
    },
    events : [
       {'id':1, 'start': new Date(year, month, day, 12), 'end': new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30),'title':'Lunch with Mike'},
       {'id':2, 'start': new Date(year, month, day, 14), 'end': new Date(year, month, day, 14, 45),'title':'Dev Meeting'},
       {'id':3, 'start': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 18), 'end': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 18, 45),'title':'Hair cut'},
       {'id':4, 'start': new Date(year, month, day - 1, 8), 'end': new Date(year, month, day - 1, 9, 30),'title':'Team breakfast'},
       {'id':5, 'start': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 14), 'end': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 15),'title':'Product showcase'}
    ]
  };
```

Is it a way to transform an ics in this format or import an ics ?

Regards,

Michael.

Comment: If you are in the context of a web application you need to upload the file into the webserver, use a library for the language you are using to parse iCalendar file then output the required JavaScript output.

Comment: Thank you,
You know a librairy i can use to parse the iCalendar ?